# Postgresql WITH statement multiple deletes

Tags: postgresql, with-statement

I can do this in Postgresql?

```
with userToDelete as (
    select userid from users where condition;
) (
    delete from table1 where user_id = userToDelete;
    delete from table2 where userid = userToDelete;
    delete from table3 where user_id = userToDelete;
);
```

I looked but I didn't find anything.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need multiple CTEs:

```
with userToDelete as (
  select userid 
  from users 
  where condition
), t1 as (
  delete from table1 
  where user_id in (select userid from userToDelete)
), t2 as (
  delete from table2 
  where userid in (select userid from userToDelete)
)
delete from table3 
where user_id in (select userid from userToDelete);
```

Note there is only one single `;` to end the whole statement.